# Why are MOSFETs good for audio output?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, audio

As title.

I read some articles that says MOSFETs are good for audio output transistors and that MOSFETs act like tubes in most case.

Here is the article says why it's good:
[SCIENTIFIC PUBLICATION](http://www.vn-amps.com.ar/paper_e.htm)

The paper is not written in English so I think I need some explanations from an experienced person.

Comment: Not all mosfets are good for audio. Here’s a link referring to ones specifically for the task. http://www.exicon.info/

Comment: Audiophiles will say that nothing but tubes sound good.

Comment: @Passerby So do some of us who have bad hearing (as we get older) and want to recall those wonderful memories sitting around operating vacuum tubes in a radio transceiver we'd built while keeping warm and reading a good book by their glow on a dark and rainy night while listening and waiting to talk to a friend when they show up some moment. Sounds real good when you hear back, that night. Nothing quite like it. Transistors just don't cut that kind of ambience. It would be on a Thanksgiving night, too!

Comment: From the perspective of the engineer, the goal of an audio amplifier is to reproduce the signal as exactly as possible. Any distortion added by the amplifier degrades the quality of the amplifier. Using this criterion, the BJT is probably slightly better than the MOSFET. But MOSFET's can be OK, too. Both are better than tubes. If you want to add distortion to your music because you think it sounds better with distortion, you can add a distortion circuit before the amplifier. A lot of what is written about audio is not science or engineering based.

Comment: But tube amplifiers look very, very cool and I have no real quarrel with people who like them. Also, tube amplifiers for Guitars and Bass's make sense. They help give the instrument its characteristic sound. Nothing wrong with that at all. But the recording equipment and home reproduction equipment should not try to add more distortion (in my opinion).

Comment: Moses, MOSFETs are ***horrible*** *especially* for any kind of pre-amplifier stage. (0 cases where you'd select one for that.) JFETs yes. BJTs yes. MOSFETs no. Class-D makes sense for them. But unless *real money* is spent on the output filtering, they don't sound all that good to me. However, the entire subject is very complex these days and I simply haven't had time to try and keep up. I probably have more than just a few things yet to learn. I'll follow up on @Kartman 's link. It reads nice on the surface. But until I see the circuit details I'm not buying it much.

Comment: @mkeith A lot of "cool looking" vacuum tube amplifiers are floating about. Some I've bought use a dual vacuum tube as an initial stage for R and L inputs, but of course rely upon BJTs for the output drivers as they can be matched to the output load (speaker or headphone) without the need for an expensive (if quality made) audio transformer. The main idea is selling the "look and feel." They still use lots of global NFB, linearizing well, and produce a quality output. It's really all about appearances with these. I'm partial to them because it brings me back to childhood. No other reason.

Comment: @mkeith I struggled so hard to try and understand vacuum tubes when growing up. It was a such a hard-won insight when I finally collected up the idea of how self-biasing of the triode grid, for example, worked. It was one of those sudden-inspiration moments and it changed my life in a way.

Comment: "Here is the article says why it's good: SCIENTIFIC PUBLICATION
But the paper is not written in English " : So you came to a conclusion without reading it?

Comment: No, for very general and across the board reasons, MOSFETS are pretty poor in that type of application. Maybe the article was sponsored by someone with a vested interest. Also note that audiofool questions tend to receive short shrift on stack exchange (basically because the audiofools have never bothered to do full studies using expensive and very unbiased studio monitors)

Comment: If you look into the regular and commonplace tricks that mastering engineers do to enhance a track from the studio (before it is released) you'd realize they that use quite high degrees of distortion to achieve a preferable sound. Been there, mastered hundreds. The point is that a sh1tty tube amp adding a small richness of distortion is doing pretty much the same thing as a mastering engineer. No need to respond.

Comment: They are excellent for Class D stages (which themselves can be excellent when done right). For linear stages like Class AB they are as good as anything (BJT, Pentode ..) because the specifities of the output element are linearized by feedback (when done right). So for Class AB it comes down to the bias network and the power handling.

Comment: @Andyaka I believe that even the studio keeps some sort of distortion they want. Just like said by an audio engineer: "Distortion is not avoidable. But why don't we use it to produce pleasing sound?"

Comment: @tobalt If you can find a schematic where MOSFETs are used in class-AB without more cost, I'd love to see it. The BJT requires rather small overhead voltages, where MOSFETs (despite some low-voltage ones) tend to require some rather complex circuits to deal with the capacitances involved and the larger overhead voltages. I'm actually curious to see a well designed MOSFET class-AB stage (voltage gain about 1) that gives me pause. For once. So far, I've not seen anything worth bothering with. I'd like to change that view, if possible.

Comment: @jonk agree that a BJT pair is easier to bias with few discrete components. No added cost was no objective. But to stimulate your interest: Most CMOS opamp output stages are Class AB of course at very low power. And you know that opamps can be extremely linear due to feedback. Now these topologies could be scaled up to handle more power for sure

Comment: In theory it should be because of the kind of distortion you get (even vs odd harmonics). In practice these days 99% of audio is done in class D so that doesn't really matter

Comment: @tobalt Most class-AB stages are about greatly increasing current compliance ***and*** matching impedances to deliver maximal power. That's kind of the entire point of that final stage. Isn't it? CMOS low-power class-AB is kind of an oxymoron of sorts. Or maybe I'm missing something. By the way, you of perhaps all people here, make me think more. I love your presence here. Just saying. I'm blessed by the time you offer.

Comment: @jonk I wouldn't say that the topological principles of Class A B D etc. are restricted to (high) power stages. Class AB is a push pull driver biased such that the output is never off. That's all there is to it. You can do that at 1 uA or 100 A. That will be determined only by the On-resistance of the used MOSFETs and the load. Hope you had a good night .

Comment: This discussion is missing one little thing: MOSFET output stages are not prone to thermal runaway and are easier to parallel for current driving capacity.

Comment: The thing about high feedback versus low feedback and what order of distortion product there are is overshadowed by the fact that when you have high amounts of feedback, the amplifier clips hard or otherwise misbehaves whenever due to a transient it hits the rail limits. That's the distortion we worry about, not the cork sniffing nonsense when the device is within operational limits.  I would take a 15W tube amp over a 15W solid state amp, while vastly preferring a 500W solid state amp over either of them.

Answer (score 9):

Let's go. About 99% of audiophilia is woo-woo.

For example, SPICE simulation with MOSFET models that don't actually model subthreshold conduction and capacitance dependence on voltage will give totally wrong results. A good example of this is Douglas Self's chapter on MOSFETs in his famous book about amplifiers. The book is very good, but the MOSFET chapter is completely wrong due to incorrect SPICE models. So if you see someone posting SPICE results using MOSFETs, ask them about subthreshold.  Since the article is based on SPICE sims, and from the look of the print it dates from before the wide availability of accurate MOSFET models, it is therefore highly suspicious of being part of the 99%.

Subthreshold is a lower current range in a MOSFET where the characteristic doesn't follow the typical square law. Instead, it is exponential, like a BJT. For power MOSFETs, the "low current range" is quite wide, up to a bit less than 1A, so in practice MOSFET crossover is entirely determined by subthreshold behavior.

[image]

(pic stolen from [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-parametric-short-channel-MOS-transistor-model-for-Grotjohn-Hoefflinger/58db27c198fe740bc9542b978013f78879a18681))

So, BJTs versus MOSFETs (versus tubes) is your basic audiophile flame war bait.

For discrete small signal stages, like everything in an amplifier up to the drivers, BJTs win due to higher transconductance, more gain, less capacitance, much less capacitance dependence on voltage, work at lower Vce without running out of juice, are cheap and available, etc.

JFETs win if you want low input current noise in your input stage, so you use a pair of JFETs as differential, but then if supply voltage is high you need to cascode it, and if you want low common mode distortion you have to cascode it anyway to keep Vds constant. You could use MOSFET in your input stage like some opamps do, but good luck finding noise specs for discrete small signal FETs especially 1/f corner.

There was a fashionable audiophile woo-woo in the "no-feedback" camp which said: feedback turns low order distortion into higher order distortion therefore it is bad. And we should use components that make low order distortion, like MOSFETs or tubes, because a square law MOSFET only makes second order distortion, whereas an BJT makes many more higher order distortion harmonics due to its exponential characteristic if you look away hard enough to not see the emitter resistor. Read and understand [Bruno Putzeys "The F-Word" especially page 14](https://linearaudio.net/sites/linearaudio.net/files/volume1bp.pdf): the truth is basically, that if you follow the cult and only use a little bit of feedback, then it's true. If you do it properly and use lots of feedback however, all the distortion goes down, so it doesn't matter what components you use as long as it's well designed.

So if you want to make an amp with a significant enough amount of distortion to have a "sound" of its own, then you'll probably want to do it like Nelson Pass and have a good balance between second and third harmonic (second higher than third), which probably means tubes or MOSFETs with low feedback. If you want low distortion however, then pick the most linear small signal stages (ie, BJTs) and a topology with multipole or nested feedback and wide bandwidth so you get as much feedback as possible.

Now you were asking about the output stage.

There's lots of myths about the output stage, and the worst one is measuring THD. Most living room amps are used below 1W most of the time, so what matters is low power performance. High power THD on peaks is dominated by the loudspeaker anyway which will give like 20% THD on peaks, so who cares if the output stage adds an extra 0.1%. But due to the "who has the bigger wee-wee" contest about full power THD, amps are often optimized for that at the expense of low power performance.

Now assuming the amp is well designed it should have enough feedback to make any self respecting audiophile reach for the crucifix and garlic, which means low order non-linearities will be buried. Due to the fact that available feedback falls off as frequency increases, it is worse at correcting high order non-linearities that generate high order distortion products at high frequency.

Leaving aside common source/emitter topologies, in a normal well designed Class-AB push pull amplifier, the output stage is a basic EF2:

[image]

If it uses MOSFETs, sometimes the drivers are unnecessary but you get the idea. In this topology, all devices work with a substantial amount of class A available except the outputs. I mean the output transistors are the only ones that actually turn on and off. If they're BJTs, the drivers will also get some wide current variations but they won't turn off. All the other transistors see tiny current variations around their operating point, and a few transistors (VAS or folded cascode and its CCS buddy) see Vce swing equal to signal.

Most of the high order distortion products come from the transistors working under large signal conditions: the outputs, and a bit from the drivers. At low power (a few watts) the VAS only has a Vce swing of a few volts over its operating point of a few tens of volts, so it's in small signal conditions.

If the drivers turn off, it means the output stage is a darlington, CFP, quasicomp, all of which are wrong use of the devices, so that doesn't count towards deciding which device wins. In particular, the CFP output stage is meant to optimize high power THD at the expense of low power THD.

Anyway, if the rest of the amp does its job (high feedback, linear input stage, enough current in the input pair to not bump into slew rate limits when it shouldn't, compensation in the right place, etc) then the only significant non-linearity remaining in the first watts is the output stage crossover, which means it's basically the final frontier and the hardest to get right.

So I've measured the crossover of a lot of devices and output stage topologies. What you want is a smooth transition between both devices, without sharp changes in transconductance (gm) and current gain (hFe).

To get this information, I measured the distortion on a low amplitude sinewave while applying an offset current to the output. The goal was to get low distortion over the whole range of output currents, not just around zero.

I will post graphs and more details if you're interested, but I don't have time now, so here's the tl/dr:

---

Winner: BJTs without emitter resistors, at medium bias (50-100mA). These have enormous transconductance which basically overwhelms everything else.

Second place: Vertical MOSFETs (ie, IRFP9/240) without source resistor (or with very low value resistors), at a rather high bias (~200mA). These have a wide subthreshold region and a nice smooth crossover, but transconductance is lower than BJTs and distortion is overall higher.

Third place: Standard EF2 with BJTs and the usual 0R22-0R47 emitter resistors.

Loser: Lateral "audio" FETs (Exicon, etc) due to having ridiculously bad crossover distortion. Their subthreshold region is too narrow, which creates sharp changes in gm as they turn off.

---

In addition, BJTs have charge storage, which means they turn off slowly. And the bigger they are, the slower they turn off. This is also heavily dependent on the device itself and what kind of secret sauce the manufacturer puts in there. When the device doesn't turn off fast enough, the result is the feedback loop doing everything it can to pull charge out of the base as fast as possible (and failing), which means a sharp spike as it yanks the drivers to draw negative base current to turn the transistor off. There is a wide range of possible results: the fast Sankens and the On MJL1302/3281 and their cousins were the best of the bunch, but some were really terrible, like On/Fairchild A1302/C5200, but Toshiba A1302/C5200 was good. With the good transistors, this problem is non-existent unless you want to drive 40kHz at several amps into the load, which a living room amp never does. With the worst devices, turn-off problems appeared at a few kHz.

In addition, driver speed matters just as much as output devices turn-off speed, because the drivers are asked to pull that charge out of the base quickly. What matters is driver fT at the current they're used at (not the datasheet number at the current they're not used at). For example slow drivers like MJE15030 were terrible, and fast BJTs like A2039/C5706 were excellent.

...and in addition, the circuit influences turn-off characteristics: lowering emitter resistor values (or removing them) widens the range of current where both devices conduct, which allows more time for the one that will turn off to do so, which improves things a lot.

This does not occur with MOSFETs, they turn off smoothly.

---

Anyway. That's measurement results for the output stages (see picture titles).

X axis is output current.

Top left is current sharing for each transistor measured on emitter resistors, so on the second graph with no emitter resistors it doesn't work.

Bottom left is gm, that's transconductance, and it is the main source of distortion. One can think of 1/gm, which is expressed in ohms, as a resistor in series with an ideal output stage.

If gm is constant over the range of output current, that's just like having a simple resistor in series, which causes no distortion.

If gm varies over output current, that's like having a variable resistor in series, which adds a signal-dependent voltage, which is distortion.

The amount of this distortion is proportional to 1/gm, and the harmonic order depends on how sharp gm variations are. So, basically, a soft rounded curve is low order, a squiggly gm curve makes more high order distortion products.

Top right is current gain. For MOSFETs, gate current is inverse proportional to frequency (measurement is at 6kHz). For BJTs, at low frequency base current is the sum of output current divided by hFe, and at the upper end of the audio range capacitance begins to matter, so actual gain also becomes frequency dependent.

[image]

^ This is IRFP240/9240 biased at 120mA, and it is pretty good, very smooth gm, although not very high, around 1 S (S=Siemens=1/Ohm). These FETs have a wide subthreshold region which gives a nice crossover.

The main issue with these is gm is proportional to current, so if you want to save the planet and not run them at 120mA bias per pair, near zero current gm will drop down a lot, but it'll still be high at high current, which spoils the nice smooth crossover.

[image]

^ This is the only pair of lateral "audio" FETs still being manufactured (sold under various names, ALFET, Exicon, etc). While they have other advantages like positive tempco so the bias is always stable, their gm crossover is much worse than the vertical MOSFETs. Note different X axis range for the current.

Vertical MOSFET spice models that don't correctly account for subthreshold will also give results that look like this "W" plot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

^That's the classic MJL1302/3281 with 0R15 emitter resistors, at 15mA-50mA-100mA bias. Gm behaves as predicted by SPICE, and no matter what the bias value is, there is always a bump or a dip in the center. This is due to the emitter resistors spoiling the exponential characteristics of the BJTs, so they don't "meet" perfectly near zero current. Increasing bias current moves the crossover points away from zero but they never go away. However, for a lower bias current, average gm is much higher than with MOSFETs, which means the resulting distortion is higher order but lower amplitude. So MOSFETs would be better suited at high bias (or class A) because that gives them higher and flatter gm, while BJTs win at low bias current.

[image]

^ Finally this is the same BJTs, but without emitter resistors. This is tricky to get thermally stable. Without the resistors, the exponential characteristic of these BJTs gives a very nice crossover with flat gm. This is the absolute winner: on a 128mA output current test, it produces about 0.1% THD, pure second order, all higher harmonics below -100dB, open loop.

Comment: Love reading your posts. "but good luck finding noise specs for discrete small signal FETs especially 1/f corner." MOSFETs typically have rather high 1/f, to the point that it is even worrying for audio because it raises the noise density even in the very audible low kHz range. If I would see discrete MOSFETs I'd see no recent to ever make *this* a topic ;)

Comment: Thanks! Someone must have found some secret recipe, because now we have FET (not JFET) input opamps with low noise (OPA1652 has CMOS input stage). Not available in discretes, of course.

Comment: TI are (IMO) really way ahead their competitors with these analog components. The 1/f noise afaik is strongly influenced by the quality of the gate oxide. Charge trapping and stuff and it looks like TI simply have their processes very well under control. TSMC of the analog world basically. But even so. It still has over 100 nV/rtHz at 1 Hz. Compare that to some good BJT or JFET parts which can be way below 10 nV/rtHz.

Comment: Thanks for dedicated explanation. Designing an amplifier with discrete component is a huge project. Many of experienced persons suggest me to use integrated chip. It will save much time and get fairly good result, they said. Tube amps have relatively simple circuit to achieve the goal with ear pleasing distortion. MOSFETs are good in some condition but looks very hard to design it into output stage. So if I thinking about having best distortion characteristic, BJT will be the choice. Best ear pleasing, tubes are the choice. And MOSFETs seem not in any of them. Correct me if I get it wrong.

Comment: @Moses I would say MOSFET outputs have 3 areas where they can be beneficial: 1) Their distortions is just what you like (subjectively), particularly when run with little feedback 2) For very high power Class AB. As bob writes BJT have a tempco that can lead to runaway conditions. Making them thermally stable sacrifices some of their advantages. 3) If you are going for really high power output and/or have high efficiency demands, you go for Class D. Then the MOSFET advantages are all over the board as they can be switched fast and easily.